# Getting file not found exception when I file does exist

Tags: java, eclipse, file, file-io, filenotfoundexception

I have a java project in eclipse and have a method that reads information from a file. When I do a JUnit test on the method, it is unable to find the file even though it is in my working tree and I used the correct class path declaration.

Method to read file:

```
public static ArrayList<Issue> readIssuesFromFile(String filename) {
    ArrayList<Issue> issues = new ArrayList<Issue>();

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
        String text = "";
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            text+= sc.nextLine();
            text+= "\n";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

JUnit Test:

```
public void testReadIssueFromFile() {
    String test = "test-files/valid_file.txt";
    try {
        ArrayList<Issue> issues = IssueReader.readIssuesFromFile(testFile);
        assertEquals(issues.get(0).getIssueId(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Working Tree:

```
->Project
 ->src
  ->.java file containing method
 ->test
  ->JUnit test file
 ->test-files
  ->txt file
```

Comment: You might want to start using a build tool (like maven) and follow the suggested directory layout. Then your txt file would be placed in test/resources and could be read as a resource. The root for files depends on your environment and is risky because of this.

Comment: Not entirely. I'm a student and on projects we've done in the past that were similar I didn't need to use a build tool for layout, as the school likes a specific layout

Answer (score 0):

According to your working tree i think your path should be:

```
../test-files/valid_file.txt
```

The path you used (`test-files/valid_file.txt`) means search in the folder of your JUnit file a folder named `test-files` and search inside this folder a file named `valid_file.txt`.

According to your working tree it's not the case. So you need `..` to move to the above level where you can find the folder `test-files`.

If it still doesn't work, maybe try to debug you program by printing the paths that you have used like this:

```
try {
    /* Here you can replace the period with another path like "test-files/valid_file.txt" 
    * to see the absolute path of it
    */
    System.out.print(new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: When I tried this, the system could not find the path

Comment: @John I've updated my answer with debugging method